# Getting file creationTime c#

Tags: c#

While using WIN32_FIND_DATA to obtain the files with FindFirstFile and FindFNextFile, am trying to do a task that requires me to enumerate files from two different directories and subsequently I need to find out the files from the first directory which were created earlier than any of the files from the second directory. The trouble is the CreationTime function returns wrong, uniform values for all the files, something like 1/1/1601 3:00:00 AM. Does anyone know how to obtain the correct creation time? Maybe it's to do with FILETIME type for fCreationTime ,i don't know.

I have got...

---

```
> struct NameAndDate
>     {
>         public string Name;
>         public DateTime Date;
>         public NameAndDate(string name, DateTime date)
>         {
>             Name = name;
>             Date = date;
>         }
>     }    
     for (int i = 0; i < AllFiles.Count; i++)
>      tmp[i] = new NameAndDate(AllFiles[i], File.GetCreationTime(AllFiles[i]));
```

---

ALLFiles is a list of files in a given directory and i am storing the files in an array of type struct that holds the name of a file and it's creation time. This will make it easier for me to do my comparison task. Note that i have also tried to use ..

```
FileInfo fd = new FileInfo(AllFiles[i]);
 tmp[i] = new NameAndDate(AllFiles[i], fd.CreationTime);
```

Comment: Post the code that you've tried so far as part of your question's body and it will allow others to see where you're going wrong.

Comment: What have you tried? There are many tutorials on how to do this, but we need to see what you've done so far in order to help your code along.

Comment: [FileSystemInfo.CreationTime Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: That is the value that will be obtained when a file doesn't exist.  Seems like there may be a bug in your code that is causing you to call the `CreationTime` check against a non-existent file.  Post your code and we can see for sure.

Comment: Are the files on a network drive?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consult the documentation, particularly the `Remarks` section:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime(v=vs.110).aspx

2 points it raises that you should find interesting

1 - May not be accurate:

> This method may return an inaccurate value, because it uses native functions whose values may not be continuously updated by the operating system.

2 - It will return the date value you mentioned if the file was not found, for whatever reason:

> If the file described in the path parameter does not exist, this method returns **12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D.** (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.

Double check that the file names that you are enumerating do indeed exist...!

HTH,

Comment: The files infact do exist. I have double checked . I am even able to display their names, its only the dates which are wrongly displayed.

Comment: If it's from a network directory, check the permissions set.

Answer (score 0):

**Correct version of your program --**

```
public struct NameAndDate
     {
         public string Name;
         public DateTime Date;
         public NameAndDate(string name, DateTime date)
         {
             Name = name;
             Date = date;
         }
     }   
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\TestPath");
FileInfo[] AllFiles = d.GetFiles("*.*");  // Whatever file type you want.

NameAndDate[] tmp = new NameAndDate[AllFiles.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < AllFiles.Length; i++)
    tmp[i] = new NameAndDate(AllFiles[i].Name, AllFiles[i].CreationTime);

foreach(var v in tmp)
    Console.WriteLine(v.Date);
```

Comment: I have tried to change but still getting the same weired  date values bro.

Comment: @MkusaOneMooxSakala : Then there must be something else you might be missing, the above-given code works fine, it's tested.